# How to make Sublime behave like Vim while folding code?

Tags: gvim, sublime-text, code-folding

I'm recently moving from Vim to Sublime. Then I find some differences here, when I fold some code in Sublime, it automatically select those code, then I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

Furthermore, if I move cursor up and down just after folding code(like <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>), those code will be collapsed, that is kind of annoying, can I fix it?

I'm using Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Have you tried using the [vintageous](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous) plugin. I'm just starting to use it now after a long period of only vim and so far it's usable.